# Data transfer from Oracle to MySQL

Tags: mysql, macos, oracle, database-migration

Scenario:

- I'm using Mac OSX Mavericks (10.9.2) - fully upgraded.
- I have a db available on a remote Oracle Server.

Requirement:
- To have this db locally on my machine for better productivity. A free solution is what I'm looking for.

Possible Solutions:
- Install the last supported "Oracle Database 10g Release 2" for Mac and transfer the data.

> But, I'm unable to find a server from where I can download this. So, is there a place from where I can download it?

- Alternatively, install MySQL and migrate the data Oracle to MySQL.

> Installation done. But cant find a way to migrate the data. How to go about that?

- Another alternative could be to use a VM but my dev environment is quite resource consuming and running a parallel VM wont be possible.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The download page for the latest Oracle Database:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index-092322.html

Note:

> Oracle Database 10.2 and 11.1 are no longer available for download.
>   The software is available as a media or FTP request for those
>   customers who own a valid Oracle Database product license for any
>   edition.

For data migration, there are also [150k search results on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=migrate+%22from+oracle%22+to+mysql+data)

Comment: Already been thru that link, and there's no download available for Mac OSX. And I dont own a product license, so cant create a ticket. Very thankful for the link, but been there done that with no solution in hand.